# c3 graph is not lining with other graph on chrome and safari browser

Tags: javascript, css, c3.js

As can you see in this example https://jsfiddle.net/juanX/atw3edu0/6/i  I have two graphs but they are not lining with one another. I am using chrome version 51.0.2704.84. The thing is working fine on the Firefox browser.  I can't do this with css because I intend to use several dynamic graphs.

Any idea how to get this working on Chrome and Safari?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 1,52,65,89,200,566,774,200,566,300,700,123,654,852,159,321,756,821,654,123,951,753,926,45,126,345,821,821,921,13],
        ],
        types: {
            data2: 'spline'
        }
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            padding: {bottom: 0},
            min: 0
        },
        x: {
            padding: {left: 0},
            min: 0,
            show: false
        }
    }

});

var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart2',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 300, 350, 300, 100, 80, 50],
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'spline',
        }
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            padding: {bottom: 0},
            min: 0
        },
        x: {
            padding: {left: 0},
            min: 0,
            show: false
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because one of your scales goes to 1,000 c3 gives it more horizontal space by default for the labels.

It looks like you've recognised it's the padding that needs fixed, but it needs to be a padding setting at the top level in the c3.generate syntax. (The padding for the x axes seems to give space to the *right* of the axis not the left, and in proportion to the x data scale, not in pixels)

https://jsfiddle.net/atw3edu0/9/

so for chart2 (and do the same for chart1):

```
c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart2',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 300, 350, 300, 100, 80, 50],
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'spline',
        }
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            padding: {bottom: 0},
            min: 0
        },
        x: {
            padding: {left: 0},
            min: 0,
            show: false
        }
    },
    /* THIS BIT */
    padding: {
        left: 50 // set same value for for both charts
    }
});
```